# How to remove a single row from JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a table which contains delete buttons for each row.
I  use

```
int row =  table.getEditingRow(); //To fetch the current row to delete.
```

Then I use

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
model.removeRow(row);
```

This deletes a row in JTable when I delete first the first row and anything in between but If I delete the last row it still deletes the last row but then the next item to delete will make an error say if there are 3 items in table

```
Item1
Item2
Item3
```

When I delete Item 3

```
Item1
Item2
```

When I delete either Item 1 or Item 2 after it will cause an error

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 >= 2
```

No problems when I delete Item1, then Item2, then Item3 or Item2 first, then Item1, then Item3

This is how I constructed my CellEditor

```
public class JButtonEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor, ActionListener{
JTable table;
JButton button = new JButton();

public JButtonEditor(JTable table){
    this.table = table;
    button.addActionListener(this);
}

@Override
public Object getCellEditorValue() {
    return button.getText();
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
    button.setText(value.toString());
    return button;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int row = table.getEditingRow();
    int column = table.getEditingColumn();
    switch(column){
        case 3:
            manage(groupId); break;
        case 4:
            editGroup(groupId); break;
        case 5:
            deleteGroup(groupId,row); break;
    }
}

private void deleteGroup(int groupId,int row) {
    //do something here to remove the group from the database
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    model.removeRow(row);
}
```

I think that after I deleted Item3, when I delete Item1 or Item2 next it thinks that I'm still deleting Item3 and it causes an ArrayOutOfBounds error since Item3 is gone in the tablemodel?

My problem is fixed.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int row = table.getEditingRow();
    int column = table.getEditingColumn();
    fireEditingStopped(); //added this
    switch(column){
        case 3:
            manage(groupId); break;
        case 4:
            editGroup(groupId); break;
        case 5:
            deleteGroup(groupId,row); break;
    }
}
```

That's the only thing I changed and I'm still using my Cell Renderer and it now works!

Comment: Maybe the deleteRow(3) is called twice? Please post the code where you call the method.

Comment: To let us see exactly what you're doing wrong, please show your code, preferably an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: check your `row` variable. I suspect you are not using it correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) shows how I do this.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to add this `fireEditingStopped`.